# Error with function newrb in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function

I have got data set and I have to train Radial Basis Network. Size of P is 258x420, size of T is 1x420. When I run script (below) training stops when reach 283 epochs. Then show me some errors in command window. Could you tell me what I have to do? Where is the problem?

> ??? Error using ==> set
>   Invalid handle.
>
> Error in ==> D:\MathLab6.5\toolbox\nnet\nnet\plotperf.m
>   On line 133  ==> set(ud.TrainLine(4),...
>
> Error in ==> D:\MathLab6.5\toolbox\nnet\nnet\newrb.m (designrb)
>   On line 210  ==>     flag_stop=plotperf(tr,eg,'NEWRB',k);
>
> Error in ==> D:\MathLab6.5\toolbox\nnet\nnet\newrb.m
>   On line 130  ==> [w1,b1,w2,b2,tr] = designrb(p,t,goal,spread,mn,df);
>
> Error in ==> D:\MathLab6.5\work\RB.m
>   On line 14  ==>         net=newrb(P,T,eg,sc,me,df);

```
clear all
nntwarn off
load arrhytmia6

df = 10;    % frequency of progress displays (in neurons).
me = 250;   %for % maximum number of neurons.
eg = 0.05;  % sum-squared error goal.
sc = 0.02;  % spread constant radial basis functions.

for i=1:length(P) 
for sc=[0.1:0.1:5],
    [w1,b1,w2,b2,nr,err] = solverb(P,T,[df me eg sc]);
    a = simurb(P,w1,b1,w2,b2);
    net=newrb(P,T,eg,sc,me,df);
    a=sim(net,P);

    [T' a' (T-a)' (abs(T-a)>=0.5)']
    (1-sum(abs(T-a)>=0.5)/length(P))*100
    plot([1:length(T)],T,'r',[1:length(T)],a,'g')
    classification_correctness_ratio(i)=(1-sum(abs(T-a)>=0.5)/length(P))*100    ;
    i=i+1;
end
end
```

The Matlab version is 6.5.1.

Data set file:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=99806363598467189006

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, the problem occurs for large number of epochs, after 183 epochs of training in my case.

After that, SSE gets smaller and smaller (about $10^{-25}$) and in some moment it turns 0, so some other result turns NaN probably.

In **newrb.m** you have assignment:

```
% PROGRESS
tr.perf(k+1) = sse;
```

And this value is used in **plotperf.m** afterwards:

```
set(ud.TrainLine(4),...
'Xdata',tr.epoch(ind),...
'Ydata',tr.perf(ind),...
'linewidth',2,'color','b');
```

So basically you want to draw plot using non-numeric value of `sse` when you expect numeric one. That is why Matlab complains on problems with graphics handler.

You should stop training the network before this happens (say about epoch=100).